# Sending and receiving gis data to map

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, openlayers, gis, geospatial

I have a spatial database in Sql server and I am working in asp.net mvc.
My project must show stored shape in web page that uses openlayers js and user must see and edit shapes and send the result to server.
I want to know how can I send data to my map and receive new data from it and save data to database.

Is there any library that work for me?
Is is not important that it must be open source

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two solutions available to you:

1. either you use openLayers ["save" strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Save-js.html), that you attach to your WFS vector layer, where you draw features and it saves your features for you with the help of your mapServer
2. or you save your features (which I prefer) yourself. Just serialiaze your VectorLayer.features feature collection, translate geometries using OpenLayers.Format.WKT parser to get the WKT of your geometries and then use simple INSERT, UPDATE to put your WKT into your database and convert it back to geometry with the help of a spatial function. (you didn't mention the type of your SQL server, so I put here an MS SQL example string in C#

`string insertString = "INSERT INTO myTable(geometry) VALUES(geometry::STGeomFromText('" + objFeature.WKTString + @"',5514)";`